# Show last user to edit a document in Microsoft Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word

Is there a way to see what user edited a document that was created by a different user? One of my employees is making unauthorized changes to unprotected documents, and I'd like to figure out who it is. The program being used is Word 2007.

Comment: If the documents aren't protected then how could the edits be unauthorized?

Comment: @joeqwerty They're probably simply told "Don't do it" and no system is in place to prevent it

Answer (score 2):

You can find this under File > Info while you have the document open. This screenshot is from Word 2010 but I believe 2007 is similar:

[image]

It is trivial to modify this field, so if they really wanted to, you can make this look like someone else.